# How to establish communication between specific nodes in Vanet?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo, traffic-simulation

I have SUMO, Omnet++, Inet, veins and Vanet to estblish the communication between nodes (Vehicles in SUMO) in my simulation. I did message passing between the Nodes(Vehicles) in omnet++ using VANET But the message is passing between all the nodes available in the scenario. So how can I establish the communication between specific desired nodes? How can I stop message multicasting in VANET?

Answer (score 1):

Support of unicast is available with plexe-veins. Its available at https://plexe.car2x.org/ For more details please explore the documentation section on home page.

Comment: That is a virtual machine right? It is not possible in Omnet++? Plexe is the only way to achieve it??

Comment: Unicast support is available from veins 4.7 onwards

Comment: Instant veins and Instant Plexe both are available for download as vms